# How to input text in a file in a specific line?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, echo

what am trying to do is to input the command `sudo` in a file with `echo` or something similar  but not in the first line but in another line after a text
ie. I have this text

`line[4]command=sh -c "service apache2 start"`
and I want the sudo to be after "command="
how to do this with `echo` or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/command=/&sudo /' file
```

explanation: examining the file line-by-line, replace the text "command=" with "command=sudo ". The `&` in the replacement string will be whatever is matched from the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, note that one usually has several scriptable text editors available on a Unix or a Linux system, in addition to the stream editor `sed`.  There's `ex`, for example:

```
ex file << END
%s/^command=/&sudo /
w
END
```

Or even `ed` (This is the GNU flavour.):

```
ed file << END
1,$s/^command=/&sudo /
w
END
```